# gstreamer debayering on GPU: Insight needed for slow conversion time

Tags: gpu, opencl, gstreamer, imx6

## Short discription

Gstreamer pipeline works but runs slow (~1FPS) when offloading debayer to GPU. I'd like some insight in why this happens, and if there is any way to improve this behaviour.

## Full story

### Context

- Tested Hardware: IMX6DL (Duallite). Has a Vivante GC880 GPU
- Linux version: 5.4.70-F+S
- DMA: ION-allocator
- Gstreamer version (& plugins): 1.16.2-imx
- OpenGL 3.0

### Goal

We are developing a revision of our hardware, which uses an **IMX6 Duallite** core through our **efus A9** computer on module. My task is to interface our **ov9732** camera, which should be used to output a **640x480 YUY2** image.

### The method

To accomplish this, I've had to write a camera driver, which is then integrated into a **gstreamer pipeline**. The camera does not debayer itself, so this has to be done somewhere in the gstreamer pipeline.
The used pipeline can be viewed further below. It does the following steps:

1. Take in the camera image
2. Convert the image from bayer to rgba
3. Convert the rgba image to YUY2
4. Expose a video sink that our streamer can use.

### Problem #1 (which is solved)

**Bayer conversion is slow**, and doing it on the CPU takes too much of our processing power. Instead, I've opted to do this task on the GPU. Unfortunately,**gstreamer does not support uploading video-bayer to the GPU (or color convert it), so I had to integrate debayering into the opengl plugin of the gstreamer-base-plugins**.

This works: **glupload** can now upload **video/x-bayer to video/x-bayer(Memory:GLMemory)** and **glcolorconvert** can convert **video/x-bayer(Memory:GLMemory) to video/x-raw(Memory:GLMemory)**

Here is the used pipeline as a reference (the RGBA -> YUY2 part is offloaded to the IPU, a very quick process) :

```
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug-level=$GST_DEBUG_LEVEL imxv4l2videosrc device=/dev/video0 ! "video/x-bayer,format=bggr,width=640,height=480,framerate=15/1" ! glupload   ! glcolorconvert ! "video/x-raw(memory:GLMemory),format=RGBA,framerate=15/1" ! gldownload ! imxipuvideotransform ! "video/x-raw,format=YUY2,framerate=15/1"  ! tee name=tp !   queue  ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video2
```

### Problem #2 (open)

Despite our modified pipeline generating a correctly debayered image, the framerate is unacceptably slow (~1fps).
I suspect the slow framerate has something to do with the underlying DRM format.
The code snippet below is my modified version of the **_drm_rgba_fourcc_from_info** function in **gsteglimage.c**, which is part of the negotiation for the underlying  **DMA buf**.
when using below return format:

```c
      *out_format = GST_GL_RED; 
      return DRM_FORMAT_R8;
```

The pipeline shows a correct image after all processing, but is slow.

When using a range of other formats, e.g. this one:

```c
      //*out_format = GST_GL_RGBA;
      //return rgba_fourcc;
```

The end image is distorted (e.g. 2 parallel monochrome images), but **runs smoothly**

The full method can be find below:

```c
/*
 * GStreamer format descriptions differ from DRM formats as the representation
 * is relative to a register, hence in native endianness. To reduce the driver
 * requirement, we only import with a subset of texture formats and use
 * shaders to convert. This way we avoid having to use external texture
 * target.
 */
static int
_drm_rgba_fourcc_from_info (GstVideoInfo * info, int plane,
    GstGLFormat * out_format)
{
  GstVideoFormat format = GST_VIDEO_INFO_FORMAT (info);
#if G_BYTE_ORDER == G_LITTLE_ENDIAN
  const gint rgba_fourcc = DRM_FORMAT_ABGR8888;
  const gint rgb_fourcc = DRM_FORMAT_BGR888;
  const gint rg_fourcc = DRM_FORMAT_GR88;
#else
  const gint rgba_fourcc = DRM_FORMAT_RGBA8888;
  const gint rgb_fourcc = DRM_FORMAT_RGB888;
  const gint rg_fourcc = DRM_FORMAT_RG88;
#endif

  GST_DEBUG ("Getting DRM fourcc for %s plane %i",
      gst_video_format_to_string (format), plane);

  switch (format) {
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_RGB16:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_BGR16:
      *out_format = GST_GL_RGB565;
      return DRM_FORMAT_RGB565;

    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_RGB:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_BGR:
      *out_format = GST_GL_RGB;
      return rgb_fourcc;

    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_RGBA:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_RGBx:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_BGRA:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_BGRx:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_ARGB:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_xRGB:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_ABGR:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_xBGR:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_AYUV:
      *out_format = GST_GL_RGBA;
      return rgba_fourcc;

    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_GRAY8:
      *out_format = GST_GL_RED;
      return DRM_FORMAT_R8;

    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_YUY2:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_UYVY:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_GRAY16_LE:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_GRAY16_BE:
      *out_format = GST_GL_RG;
      return rg_fourcc;

    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_NV12:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_NV21:
      *out_format = plane == 0 ? GST_GL_RED : GST_GL_RG;
      return plane == 0 ? DRM_FORMAT_R8 : rg_fourcc;

    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_I420:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_YV12:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_Y41B:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_Y42B:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_Y444:
      *out_format = GST_GL_RED;
      return DRM_FORMAT_R8;
    /* Cases added by me*/
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_rggb:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_bggr:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_grbg:
    case GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_gbrg:
      /*the below formats produce a correct bayer format, but upload is slow*/
      *out_format = GST_GL_RED; 
      return DRM_FORMAT_R8; 
      /*Changing the DRM_FORMAT to the incorrect ones below 
        changes the output (after YUY2 conversion) to a distorted image ( 2 split-screen images, with one    red and one blue), but has a smooth framerate of 15 FPS*/ 
      //*out_format = GST_GL_RGBA;
      //return rgba_fourcc;
    default:
      GST_ERROR ("Unsupported format for DMABuf.");
      return -1;
  }
}
```

It puzzles me why simply changing the DRM_FORMAT results in a smooth stream (albeit with a wrong image). The steps the pipeline takes are still the same. I'm 100% certain that in both cases the debayering step is done and takes place on the CPU. The algorithm is based on [this paper](https://casual-effects.com/research/McGuire2009Bayer/index.html). I can provide the full source if anyone needs it.

So in conclusion: Can anyone provide a reason why the pipeline is slow, or at least point me in a direction of why `DRM_FORMAT_R8` results in such a slow pipeline? Any help is greatly appreciated.

I can provide any of the modified Gstreamer code, or the opencl code if desired.

To verify dma is used instead of raw data, I've put a breakpoint in `_dma_buf_upload_accept` function of the `gstglupload.c` source code. It is hit each frame.

If I wouldn't have modified  `_drm_rgba_fourcc_from_info`, this method would return `-1` and `gstupload.c` would eventually fallback to `_raw_data_upload_accept`.